# How can I send value from Swift code to C Wrapper

Tags: ios, c, swift, wrapper

In a swift view controller we have a slide bar which updates a value when moved. This value we need in a wrapper.mm file, we have imported the wrap.h in the header but are unable to understand how the functions work to send a variable over.

**Swift code:**

```
var brightness = 0;

@IBAction funf sendBrightness(_ sender: UISlider) {
  brightness = Int(senderl.value)
}
```

**Using the header to call the wrapper:**

```
#import "DlibWrapper.h"
```

**Main method used in the Wrapper is defined like this:**

```
(void)doWorkOnSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer inRects:(NSArray<NSValue *> *)rects;
```

**How can I send over another value?**

**This is called in the SWIFT As follows, also dont understand WHY this works:**

```
let wrapper = DlibWrapper()

wrapper?.doWork(on: sampleBuffer, inRects: boundsArray)
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to determine what your code is doing. All I see is an empty `doWork` function being called and an InterfaceBuilder outlet to a slider.

Comment: @Brandon, the content of the function are not relevant to the question, I just want to understand how to send a variable from the slider saved in "brightness" to the wrapper function and use it inside. Thanks for the response

Comment: your question is too broad and generic, we don't have enough information to help you. You may want to read some docs about the bridging technique between objC and swift

Comment: @Pedro; You can either `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"` as per: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c OR write a function that takes an int and have the above IBAction callback call that function..